# Is there anything glaringly wrong with my .ajaxSetup jquery call?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to debug some code and get to the bottom of the error.

Is there anything wrong with this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ 
beforeSend: function(xhr) {  
     xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript"); }
});
```

This is in jQuery by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ajax event `BeforeSend` is local in every ajax call, AFAIK you can't use it in `$.ajaxSetup` but you can use his global version `ajaxSend` in this way:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    ajaxSend: function(event, xhr, options) {
        /* code here */
    }
});
```

For more info about ajax events in jQuery and their execution order take a look here: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events

Comment: Just a note that currently, the correct way to set ajaxSend handler is by call $(document).ajaxSend(). According to ```http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/``` (see note near bottom of that page), ajaxSend should not be set as an option to .ajaxSetup()